# Using the filter Function in Xcode with a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, swift, filter, nsmutablearray, uisearchresultscontroller

I am trying to make an app, with a list of movie titles, with a search function, the list of movies is imported into the appellation via a text file, I am having issues using the `filter` function given in `Xcode`, I know it's meant to look something along these lines, but what would I put in the area for "AnyObject"

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {

    self.filteredMovies = self.arrayMovies.filter { (<#AnyObject#>) -> Bool in
        return true
    }


    self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

These are what my variables are

```
var dictMovies = [String:String]()
var arrayMovies = NSMutableArray()
var searchController : UISearchController!
var resultsController = UITableViewController()
var filteredMovies = [String]()
```

I hope that's enough information for someone to give out some information. :D

EDIT This is what Im storing in the arrayMovies

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("movielist2", ofType: "txt")

    let filemgr = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if filemgr.fileExistsAtPath(path!){

        do{

            let fullText = try String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            let readings = fullText.componentsSeparatedByString("@") as [String]

            for i in 1..<readings.count {

                let movieData = readings[i].componentsSeparatedByString("\t")

                dictMovies["MovieTitle1"] = "\(movieData[0])"
                dictMovies["MovieYear"] = "\(movieData[1])"


                arrayMovies.addObject(dictMovies)
            }

        } catch let error as NSError{
            print("Error: \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: What kind of object are you storing in `arrayMovies`?  (Also, why not use Swift data types instead of NS* ones?)

Comment: As always, **use native Swift `Array` rather than unrelated Foundation `NSMutableArray`**. The compiler has no idea – me neither – what the array actually contains.

Comment: hey sorry Im still very new to coding, this is what Im storing in barry movies at this stage....

Comment: let movieData = readings[i].componentsSeparatedByString("\t")
                    
                    dictMovies["MovieTitle1"] = "\(movieData[0])"
                    dictMovies["MovieYear"] = "\(movieData[1])"
                    
                    
                    arrayMovies.addObject(dictMovies)
                }

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Predicate :

```
func updateSearchResultsForSearchController(searchController: UISearchController) {
           let resultPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "name contains[c] %@", searchController.searchBar.text)
           self.filteredUserData = self.arrayMovies.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate)
           self.resultsController.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Hope This help.